# Write a query to display the name of the department that has the maximum staff count order by department name-this is the question what should i add?

Tags: database, rdbms

select department.department_name from department
join(select department_id,count(staff_id) as staff_count from staff group by department_id)s on
department.department_id=s.department_id
order by department.department_name desc ;

Answer (score 3):

It worked for me when I executed both the queries. You can try either of them.

```
    select department_name  
    from  
    (    
     select d.department_name,  
     count(*) as staff_count  
     from   department d  
     join  staff s  
     on  d.department_id=s.department_id  
     Group by d.department_name  
     Order by  staff_count  DESC  
     )  
     where rownum <= 1;
```

Or

```
    select top 1 department_name  
    from staff  
    join department  
    on s.department_id = d.department_id  
    group by department_name  
    order by count(*) desc
```